# How to test predictions after applying one-hot encoding during training using ml.net?

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding, ml.net

Below is the following snippet to do data processing

```
var pipeline = _mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.ConvertType(new[] {
    new InputOutputColumnPair("x1", "x"),
    new InputOutputColumnPair("a1", "a"),
}, 
outputKind: DataKind.Single).Append(_mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(new[] {
    new InputOutputColumnPair("b1","b"),
    new InputOutputColumnPair("c1","c")
})).Append(_mlContext.Transforms.SelectColumns("x1", "a1", "b1", "c1","Label"));
   
            data = pipeline.Fit(data).Transform(data);
    
            // Split the data into a training set and a test set
            split = _mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(data, testFraction: 0.2);
    
            // Define the target column name
            labelColumnName = nameof(Dataset.Label);
            string[] featureColumnNames = data.Schema.AsQueryable()
               .Select(column => column.Name)                               
            // Get alll the column names
               .Where(name => name != nameof(Dataset.Label)) // Do not include the Label column
               .ToArray();
    
            // Create the data process pipeline
            var dataProcessPipeline = _mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", featureColumnNames)
                                            .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMeanVariance(inputColumnName: "Features", outputColumnName: "FeaturesNormalizedByMeanVar"));
```

When I try to do a prediction like this:

```
public List<PredictionEngineOutput> Predict(string path, List<DataToPredict> dataPredict)
{
    var model = _mlContext.Model.Load(path, out var schema);
    // Create a prediction engine
    var engine = _mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<DataToPredict, PredictionEngineSchema>(model);

            List<PredictionEngineSchema> predictionList = new List<PredictionEngineSchema>();
            var predictOutput = new List<PredictionEngineOutput>();
            foreach (var data in dataPredict)
            {
                // Make the prediction
                var prediction = engine.Predict(data);
                predictionList.Add(prediction);
    
                var p = new PredictionEngineOutput
                {
                    PredictedLabel = prediction.PredictedLabel,
                    Probability = prediction.Probability,
                    Score = prediction.Score,
                    FeatureContributions = new List<float>()
                };
                predictOutput.Add(p);
                foreach (var contribution in prediction.FeatureContributions.DenseValues())
                {
                    p.FeatureContributions.Add(contribution);
                }
            }
            return predictOutput;
        }
```

An error comes up on this line: `var prediction = engine.Predict(data);`

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

When predicting I tried to do apply same transformers to the `List<DataToPredict> dataPredict` after parsing it as a `dataview`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why that issue is happening but if you're looking to predict on multiple rows / data instances, I would recommend using the `Transform` method. So it would look something like this:

```cs
var dataToPredictDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(dataPredict);
var predictions = model.Transform(dataToPredictDataView);
```

For more information, check out this [how-to guide on making predictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/machine-learning-model-predictions-ml-net#multiple-predictions-idataview).